# Firebase Listener not working during login of some users through phone authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Update: The problem went away when all the users who were facing this problem changed the mobile carrier. The problem did not reoccur when they shifted back to the original carrier. Although things are working now, it would help if I identify the cause of the error so that it can be handled properly in future

Users in my application are logging in through Firebase phone authentication. Everything was working fine before suddenly, for some users, who had earlier logged into the app but subsequently their data had been removed, are unable to login to the system afresh. The authentication process and login has stopped working for these users. I will first provide the code and then write in detail what I have figured out so far. I do some toasts (not log because these users are remote) to understand the flow.

First I do a verification of the phone number entered:

```
fun  verify(){
        verificationCallBacks()
        val mobile = "+91"+MobileNumber.text.toString()
        PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            mobile,
            60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            this,
            mCallbacks
        )
    }

fun verificationCallBacks(){

        mCallbacks = object: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){
            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Automatic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                signIn(credential)
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {

                Toast.makeText(this@Login, p0.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(p0: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Verification ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                super.onCodeSent(p0, p1)
                verificationID = p0
            }


        }
    }
```

After the verification callbacks, on a usual day, some users are automatically signed in, while some are authenticated through a verification SMS. The code for signIn and authentication (login through verification SMS) are as follows:

```
fun authenticate(){

        if(Verification.text.toString().trim().isNotEmpty()) {
            val verifyCode = Verification.text.toString()
            val credential: PhoneAuthCredential =
                PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationID, verifyCode)
            signIn(credential)
        }
    }

fun signIn(credential: PhoneAuthCredential){
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
                    task: Task<AuthResult> ->
                if(task.isSuccessful){
                    saveUserToFirebaseDatabase()
                }else{
                    if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Error Logging you in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

After the signIn method the user is saved to Database if he is not existing, or he is existing then something else is updated as follows:

```
fun saveUserToFirebaseDatabase(){
        val uid = mAuth.uid ?: ""
        ref1 = newref.child(uid)
        Toast.makeText(this@Login, uid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        listenerA1 = ref1.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(this@Login, p0.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                if(p0.exists()){

                  **** Do Something *****

                }else{
                   **** Do Something *****
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

For the users that I described before, what I see is that for them the authentication is completed but they are not able to connect to the database. The sequence of code execution, which I was able to figure out, is as follows:

1) In Verification call back both automatic sign in (onVerificationCompleted)and verification SMS (onCodeSent) are triggered. I am not sure whether this should be the case.

2) The automatic signIn directly takes the execution to the signIn function.

3) In the signIn function the uid is generated, which is displayed. But after that the firebase listener is not attached. Hence the user is unable to connect to the database. There is no message displayed against p0.message on database error.

4) In the meantime the user also receives the verification code. He inputs the same and the execution again takes him to the signIn function. But then he gets the "Error Logging you in" message. This error happens because Firebase throws an invalid exception as the "SMS sent has expired"

I am scratching my head on this for last 48 hours unable to figure out why this is happening. Can someone please help

Comment: Did you find a solution as I'm facing similar issue?

Comment: No ... even the Firebase support team could not detect anything. Seems like a carrier specific issue

Comment: Ah ok. My issue was in a PHP script server-side.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not answer your question but this is what i have learned about Firebase Auth
If you are using multiple auth providers for e.g. Google + Phone in your app it works fine the first time,
but when you reset the app, say clear app data, then try to login again with phone number first it just give you an error without any helpful message or error code.
To resolve this, I removed/deleted that specific account from firebase console manually by searching for phone number.
After deleting the account i was able to login again with the same phone number.
You could try to delete the phone number account from console and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: I have only phone authentication in my system

Comment: Did you try deleting the phone account?

Comment: yes i did...and then the problem started. There is an update which I have reported above.